# Passing an array to a GIMP module via Script-Fu

Tags: scheme, lisp, gimp, script-fu

## Minimal Working Example

I am attempting to pass an array of integers to a GIMP plugin using the [Scheme Script-Fu interface](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html). I have a source code file named `main.c` with the following content:

```c
#include <libgimp/gimp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void query (void);

static void run (
    const gchar *name,
    gint nparams,
    const GimpParam *param,
    gint *nreturn_vals,
    GimpParam **return_vals
);

const GimpPlugInInfo PLUG_IN_INFO = {
    NULL,  /* init_proc  */
    NULL,  /* quit_proc  */
    query, /* query_proc */
    run,   /* run_proc   */
};

MAIN ()

static void query (void)
{
    static GimpParamDef args[] = {
    {
      GIMP_PDB_INT32,
      "run-mode",
      "The run mode { RUN-INTERACTIVE (0), RUN-NONINTERACTIVE (1) }"
    },
    {
      GIMP_PDB_INT8ARRAY,
      "an array",
      ""
      "an array"
      }
    };

    gimp_install_procedure (
        "my-test-plugin",
        "My test plug-in",
        "Description",
        "Jane Doe <jane@doe.name>",
        "Copyright (C) Jane Doe\n"
        "http://foo.bar",
        "2017",
        g_strconcat("My test plug-in", "...", NULL),
        "RGB*, GRAY*",
        GIMP_PLUGIN,
        G_N_ELEMENTS (args),
        0,
        args, 
        NULL
    );
}

static void run (
    const gchar *name,
    gint nparams,
    const GimpParam *param,
    gint *nreturn_vals,
    GimpParam **return_vals)
{
    static GimpParam value;
    value.type = GIMP_PDB_STATUS;
    value.data.d_status = GIMP_PDB_SUCCESS;
    *nreturn_vals = 1;
    *return_vals = &value;

    FILE* out = fopen("mylog.log", "w");
    fprintf(out, "Parameter #0:\t%d\nParameter #1:\t", param[0].data.d_int32);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        fprintf(out, "%d ", param[1].data.d_int8array[i]);
    fprintf(out, "\n");
    fclose(out);
}
```

I compile and install the file as a GIMP plugin on as follows:

```
sudo apt install libgimp2.0-dev
gcc `gimptool-2.0 --cflags --libs` main.c
gimptool-2.0 --install-bin ./a.out
```

I am doing this on a Debian 9 box.
When I attempt to run the plugin using the Script-Fu interface:

```
(my-test-plugin 1 #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16))
```

[image: Calling the plugin via Script-Fu]

a file named `mylog.log` gets created with the following content:

```
Parameter #0:   1
Parameter #1:   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 201 246 126 174 85 0 0
```

whereas the following is the expected content:

```
Parameter #0:   1
Parameter #1:   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

## The Real-World Version

I am attempting to use [the `gimp-plugin-morphop` GIMP plugin](https://github.com/alessandrofrancesconi/gimp-plugin-morphop) using the [Scheme Script-Fu interface](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html). When I use the GUI, the plugin works as expected:

[image: Hit-or-Miss via GUI #1]
[image: Hit-or-Miss via GUI #1]

However, when I use the following Script-Fu script:

```lisp
(plug-in-morphop RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 1 2 6 7
  #(-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
    -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1
    -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
    -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1) 24 2)
```

the plugin does not produce the expected result:

[image: Hit-or-Miss via Script-Fu #1]
[image: Hit-or-Miss via Script-Fu #1]

I modified the plugin to see what the actual difference was:

```
diff --git a/src/morphop-algorithms.c b/src/morphop-algorithms.c
index b927ba3..9dff320 100644
--- a/src/morphop-algorithms.c
+++ b/src/morphop-algorithms.c
@@ -166,7 +166,16 @@ void start_operation(GimpDrawable *drawable, GimpPreview *preview, MorphOpSettin
                GimpPixelRgn src_rgn_c, dst_rgn_c;
                guchar* src_preview_c = NULL, *dst_preview_c = NULL;

+               FILE* log = fopen("morphop-operation.log", "w");
                int i, j;
+               for(i = 0; i < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
+                       for(j = 0; j < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; j++) {
+                               fprintf(log, "%d ", settings.element.matrix[i][j]);
+                       }
+                       fprintf(log, "\n");
+               }
+               fclose(log);
+
                // white structuring element
                for(i = 0; i < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
                        for(j = 0; j < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; j++) {
```

After using the module through the GUI, the `morphop-operation.log` file contains the following text:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 
-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1 
-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1 
-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1 
-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

as expected. After running the Script-Fu code, the `morphop-operation.log` file contains the following text:

```
-1 0 0 86 0 103 114 
-1 64 0 0 0 45 112 
-1 41 64 0 0 105 104 
-1 8 42 33 0 110 111 
-1 95 8 0 112 45 112 
-1 36 95 0 108 109 0 
-1 86 36 0 117 111 32
```

where the rightmost six integers on each row appear to be random garbage that changes at every invocation. Since `settings.element.matrix` is already an internal representation of the received array, I modified the plugin a little further to display the received array directly:

```
diff --git a/src/morphop.c b/src/morphop.c
index 3895770..cb814b6 100644
--- a/src/morphop.c
+++ b/src/morphop.c
@@ -150,9 +150,16 @@ static void run (
                                }

                                msettings.operator = param[3].data.d_int32;
-                               
+                       
+                               FILE* log = fopen("morphop-init.log", "w");
                                int i;
                                for (i = 0; i < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE * STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
+                                       fprintf(log, "%d ", param[5].data.d_int8array[i]);
+                               }
+                               fprintf(log, "\n");
+                               fclose(log);
+
+                               for (i = 0; i < STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE * STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
                                        msettings.element.matrix[i % STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE][(int)ceil((i + 1.0) / STRELEM_DEFAULT_SIZE) - 1] = param[5].data.d_int8array[i];
                                }
```

After running the Script-Fu code, the `morphop-init.log` file contains the following text:

```
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 64 169 248 158 193 85 0 0 64 170 248 158 193 85 0 0 33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 112 108 117 103 45 105 110 45 109 111 114 112 104 111 112 0 32
```

The values beyond the eighth appear to be random garbage, although some retain their value across several runs:

```
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 64 89 10 89 79 86 0 0 64 90 10 89 79 86 0 0 33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 112 108 117 103 45 105 110 45 109 111 114 112 104 111 112 0 32
```

```
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 64 217 110 172 167 85 0 0 64 218 110 172 167 85 0 0 33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 112 108 117 103 45 105 110 45 109 111 114 112 104 111 112 0 32
```

To me this signifies that the array is passed in a different format that the one expected by the plug-in. How do I pass an array into a GIMP plug-in via Script-Fu, so that it stays intact?

Comment: Just completely guessing, is it possible that in output from morphop-operation.log is matrix transposed? So first column is correctly passed in as original first line and after that is all garbage? Maybe end of lines in your sccript are messing all up?  ...
  (plug-in-morphop RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 1 2 6 7 #(-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 here
    -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 here
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1 here
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1 etc..
    -1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1
    -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
    -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1)

Comment: (i) Indeed, it is transposed. See the bottom context of the second diff, the `msettings.element.matrix` array is a transposed version of the input matrix `param[5].data.d_int8array`. (ii) No, the newlines have no bearing on the result.

Comment: what about this? (plug-in-morphop RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 1 2 6 7 #([-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
    [-1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
    [-1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1]
    [-1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1]
    [-1 -1  0  0  0 -1 -1]
    [-1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
    [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]) 24 2)

Comment: There seems to be some type checking in place: `Error: ( : 21918) Item 1 in vector is not a number (argument 6 for function plug-in-morphop) #([-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1] [-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1] [-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1] [-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1] [-1 -1 0 0 0 -1 -1] [-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1] [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the API, it is [necessary to pass the size of the array before the array](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-developer/6165-problem-returning-arrays-in-plugins).

```
--- /tmp/plugin.orig    2017-04-02 16:45:34.902108610 +0200
+++ /tmp/plugin.c   2017-04-02 16:43:26.510105281 +0200
@@ -30,6 +30,11 @@
       "The run mode { RUN-INTERACTIVE (0), RUN-NONINTERACTIVE (1) }"
     },
     {
+      GIMP_PDB_INT32,
+      "array-size",
+      "The array bellow"
+    },
+    {
       GIMP_PDB_INT8ARRAY,
       "an array",
       ""
@@ -69,9 +74,9 @@
     *return_vals = &value;

     FILE* out = fopen("mylog.log", "w");
-    fprintf(out, "Parameter #0:\t%d\nParameter #1:\t", param[0].data.d_int32);
+    fprintf(out, "Parameter #0:\t%d\nParameter #2:\t", param[0].data.d_int32);
     for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
-        fprintf(out, "%d ", param[1].data.d_int8array[i]);
+        fprintf(out, "%d ", param[2].data.d_int8array[i]);
     fprintf(out, "\n");
     fclose(out);
 }
```

Then:

```
 > (my-test-plugin 1 16 #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16))
 (#t)
```

Results in:

```
$ cat mylog.log 
Parameter #0:   1
Parameter #2:   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

And you can verify the parameters are implicitly linked by making the size larger than the length:

```
> (my-test-plugin 1 17 #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15))
Error: ( : 1) INT8 vector (argument 3) for function my-test-plugin has
size of 15 but expected size of 17
```

(The preceding parameter being RUN-NONINTERACTIVE (1) or element-size (7), explains the differing amounts of available array contents in your 2 tests.)

Comment: Indeed, that appears to be the issue; thank you! The documentation at <http://developer.gimp.org> is not exactly helpful (it mostly just lists the various type and method definitions). Is there a better resource or is a plugin developer expected to be familiar with the libgimp codebase?

Comment: @Witiko glad that was it. I find it rather hard to debug these in ways other than the ones you tried, though examples from integrated/active/popular procedures should be a bit safer and hopefully always show correlations like the redundant size parameters before arrays. Finding the code is also tricky till you've forced an error (or something in tracing,) i.e. the error I forced to verify the issue finally gets me to the code: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp-tiny-fu/tree/tiny-fu/ts-wrapper.c#n914

Comment: Well, what do you know; I also managed to find that code, but somehow the `args[i-1].data.d_int32` part did not click for me. :-)